# Preserve Hibernate Lazy loading in data transfer object design pattern

Tags: java, hibernate, design-patterns, lazy-loading, dto

I usually work on 3-tier applications using Hibernate in the persistence layer and I take care to not use the domain model classes in the presentation layer. This is why I use the `DTO (Data Transfer Object)` design pattern.

But I always have a dilemma in my entity-dto mapping. Whether I lose the lazy loading benefict, or I create complexity in the code by introducing filters to call or not the domain model `getters`.

---

**Example :** *Consider a DTO UserDto that corresponds to the entity User*

```
public UserDto toDto(User entity, OptionList... optionList) {

        if (entity == null) {
            return null;
        }

        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        userDto.setId(entity.getId());
        userDto.setFirstname(entity.getFirstname());


        if (optionList.length == 0 || optionList[0].contains(User.class, UserOptionList.AUTHORIZATION)) {
            IGenericEntityDtoConverter<Authorization, AuthorizationDto> authorizationConverter = converterRegistry.getConverter(Authorization.class);

            List<AuthorizationDto> authorizations = new ArrayList<>(authorizationConverter.toListDto(entity.getAuthorizations(), optionList));
            userDto.setAuthorizations(authorizations);

...
}
```

`OptionList` is used to filter the mapping and map just what is wanted.

Although the last solution allow lazy loading but it's very heavy because the `optionList` must be specified in the service layer.

---

**Is there any better solution to preserve lazy loading in a DTO design pattern ?**

Comment: How is it working ? Most of the time, when you use DTO / 3-tier, the transaction is closed when you get out of the service layer. How your lazy loading in working then ? If you use the open session in view pattern, why not use directly hibernate entities, which already implements lazy loading ? You can have several entities for the same table, use a specialized one for UI, that you set in read-only mode when loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your response Thierry.  Actually the lazy loading is done in the service layer. The presentation layer just tell the service layer what it needs to be retreived using the `optionList` which is next used to call or not the getter of the domain model. Like this, it prevent a database call to be done where it's not necessary. 

Example of service :

`@Transactional
 public UserDto findByName(String name, final OptionList... optionList) {
  return getConverter().toDto(dao.findByName(name), optionList);
 } `

Comment: ok, i understand your question better now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the same entity persistent state, I don't like having fields of an object un-initialized in some execution path, while these fields might also be initialized in other cases. This cause too much headache to maintain :

- it will cause Nullpointer in the better cases
- if `null` is also a valid option (and thus not cause NullPointer), it could mean the data was removed and might trigger unexpected removal business rules, while the data is in fact still there.

I would rather create a DTO hierarchy of interfaces and/or classes, starting with `UserDto`. All of the actual dto implementation fields are filled to mirror the persistent state : if there is data, the field of the dto is not null.

So then you just need to ask the service layer which implementation of the Dto you want :

```
public <T extends UserDto> T toDto(User entity, Class<T> dtoClass) {
    ...
}
```

Then in the service layer, you could have a :

```
Map<Class<? extends UserDto>, UserDtoBUilder> userDtoBuilders = ...
```

where you register the different builders that will create and initialize the various UserDto implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want lazy loading, but I guess because your  `UserDto` serves multiple representations through `optionList` configuration?
I don't know how your presentation layer code looks like, but I guess you have lot's of if-else code for each element in `optionList`?

How about having different representations i.e. subclasses instead? I'm asking this because I'd like to suggest giving [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://blazebit.com/blog/2016/getting-started-with-blaze-persistence-entity-views.html) a try. Here a little code example that fits to your domain.

```
@EntityView(User.class)
public interface SimpleUserView {
    // The id of the user entity
    @IdMapping("id") int getId();

    String getFirstname();
}

@EntityView(Authorization.class)
public interface AuthorizationView {

    // The id of the authorization entity
    @IdMapping("id") int getId();

    // Whatever properties you want
}

@EntityView(User.class)
public interface AuthorizationUserView extends SimpleUserView {

    List<AuthorizationView> getAuthorizations();
}
```

These are the *DTOs* with some metadata about the mapping to the entity model. And here comes the usage:

```
@Transactional
public <T> T findByName(String name, EntityViewSetting<T, CriteriaBuilder<T>> setting) {
    // Omitted DAO part for brevity

    EntityManager entityManager = // jpa entity manager
    CriteriaBuilderFactory cbf = // query builder factory from Blaze-Persistence
    EntityViewManager evm = // manager that can apply entity views to query builders

    CriteriaBuilder<User> builder = cbf.create(entityManager, User.class)
        .where("name").eq(name);
    List<T> result = evm.applySetting(builder, setting)
        .getResultList();
    return result;
}
```

Now if you use it like `service.findByName("someName", EntityViewSetting.create(SimpleUserView.class))` it will generate a query like

```
SELECT u.id, u.firstname 
FROM User u 
WHERE u.name = :param_1
```

and if you use the other view like `service.findByName("someName", EntityViewSetting.create(AuthorizationUserView.class))` it will generate

```
SELECT u.id, u.firstname, a.id 
FROM User u LEFT JOIN u.authorizations a 
WHERE u.name = :param_1
```

Apart from being able to get rid of the manual object mapping, the performance will improve because of using optimized queries!

Comment: Hi Christian, thank you for your reply.  Indeed, your solution improve performance. I want to know how do you deal with your evm.applySetting and what actually does ?

Comment: It applies the projections from the entity view class to the query builder `builder` and registers a so called `ObjectBuilder` on it. That object builder will take the tuples from the query result and build objects of your entity view type.